# Как програмировать Apache

Tags: apache

Как програмировать Apache? Какой язык использовать? И вообще, чего можно спомощью него делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется Вы что-то путаете, судя по [статье из вики](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_AH-64_Apache) у Apache нет программного обеспечения (а если и есть, то всё уже "запрограммировано" :)

А если серьезно, то мне кажется, что у Вас каша в голове. [Apache](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache) - "свободный веб-сервер". "программировать" под него можно на разных "языках", Вам же на мой взгляд нужно смотреть в сторону html и php. Но сначала почитайте основы сетевых технологий. Когда будете знать, что такое пакет и как работает протокол http - тогда можно будет о чем-то говорить :)

Вообще, очень советую использовать гугл. Есть вопрос - первым делом не на хешкод забегать, а заходить в гугл и вбивать его в строку запроса. Сразу вопросов меньше станет, гарантирую.

Answer (score 0):

Apache не программируют,его настраивают